# Questions orders isn't correct

Tags: bug, search, sorting, question-lists

Sometimes when I am searching for two or more tags to filter questions, for example  [java & swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing?sort=newest&pageSize=15), order by newest, but on first page I can see too old questions, see my screenshots from first page that I see on my PC.

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

Is this caused by caching (my favorite tags) that I can't reset somehow?

Comment: I hate to use a meme here, but we definately need some freehand circles (or a circle of some kind).  I have no idea what you are trying to say.  This is just a wall of pictures.

Comment: Clarifying the OP: try going to page 2, it'll again show questions of today while the bottom of page 1 shows questions from years ago.

Comment: It is definitely wrong right now.  Might be better an hour from now.  A workaround is to only select on [swing], everybody tags it with [java] as well.